# MySql exclude a result with a certain ID?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my SQL statement

```
            SELECT * FROM schedule
            WHERE teacher_id = '$teacher_id'
            AND event_id <> '$event_id'
            AND seconds_start = '$start_time'
            OR (seconds_start < '$start_time' AND seconds_end > '$start_time')
            OR (seconds_start < '$end_time' AND seconds_end >= '$end_time')
```

As you can see, I want to exclude any results with a certain ID, however this seems to not be working because...

[image]

Shouldn't this behave as expected??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously don't understand [Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html)

You can rarely mix `AND` and `OR` operators in the same instruction, without specifying their scope with parenthesis.

Properly indenting your code following the parenthesis also help to understand your query:

```
    SELECT * FROM schedule
    WHERE teacher_id = '$teacher_id'
      AND event_id <> '$event_id'
      AND ( 
             seconds_start = '$start_time'
         OR (seconds_start < '$start_time' AND seconds_end > '$start_time')
         OR (seconds_start < '$end_time' AND seconds_end >= '$end_time')
        )
```

Comment: That indenting is a great idea.

Comment: indenting is a best coding practice in any programming language.

Comment: I tend to forget that with SQL, this is a timely reminder for me, could have saved me some time this morning.

Comment: Its at least as much important with SQL as it is for other languages.. When you'll come to build massive queries of hundred lines with tenth of jjoined tables and nested queries, you'll remind this :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to group your `second_start`

```
    SELECT * FROM schedule
    WHERE teacher_id = '$teacher_id'
    AND event_id <> '$event_id'
    AND (seconds_start = '$start_time'
    OR (seconds_start < '$start_time' AND seconds_end > '$start_time')
    OR (seconds_start < '$end_time' AND seconds_end >= '$end_time'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `OR` part makes your statement ignore your limitation of the event_id.

As Jon Stirling pointed out, you need to set your parenthesis  accordingly.

```
    SELECT * FROM schedule
    WHERE teacher_id = '$teacher_id'
    AND event_id <> '$event_id'
    AND (
        seconds_start = '$start_time'
        OR (seconds_start < '$start_time' AND seconds_end > '$start_time')
        OR (seconds_start < '$end_time' AND seconds_end >= '$end_time')
    )
```